# PHP function byref parameter with default value

Tags: php, function, parameter-passing

I have a PHP function that I have been asked to update as business needs have changed. The original function worked like this.

```
function myFunction($var1, $var2, $var3) {
   CODE GOES HERE
}
```

For the new version, a fourth optional parameter is required. I know that I can do this like this:

```
function myFunction($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4 = "") {
    CODE GOES HERE
}
```

I created the new code and it works fine. I've just been informed that when a value is passed in for the last parameter, it needs to be byref. I searched the PHP documentation and questions here but haven't seen anything about the possibility of this. I would assume the code would work like this:

```
function myFunction($var1, $var2, $var3, &$var4 = "") {
    CODE GOES HERE
}
```

Will this work? Does PHP allow a variable to be passed by ref and also have a default value set for it if nothing is passed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does work.

Have a look here at [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/fH4HUt) to see it in action.

```
<?php

function test(&$var = "test") {
    echo $var;
}

test();
```

Outputs

```
test
```

However, there is a caveat. If you do pass a parameter, it needs to be a reference to a variable. The following will not work:

```
test("Testing");
```

Because `"Testing"` is a literal string, not a referable variable.